# What is a patch terran?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

What does it mean when they say "patch terran"?  I am looking to understand what the term means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Patch terran/zerg/protoss is a derogatory term for somebody who is only good/successful because in the current state of the balance (patch) his race is too strong.

Supposedly this player's success will quickly fade once the game has been "fixed"/balanced.

Comment: nowadays, it is usually used by those who don't understand the game though since the major imbalance from the beta/first 6 months of WoL are gone. The imbalances left are minor now.

Comment: Its HoTs now...